# What does website isolation / user isolation do Laravel Forge?

Tags: hosting, web-hosting, forge, laravel-forge

In Laravel Forge there's an option called Website Isolation, which some people also seem to mention as user isolation as well. I am not quite sure what it does and possible benefit for such functionality. It would be great if someone can explain this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that one of the biggest advantages for using Website / User Isolation is that Laravel Forge will be then able to offer unique and independent nginx environment compared to other sites exist in the same server. Thus, in situations where it requires restarting an nginx or overloading, other sites in the server should work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4):

It also means you can assign different users to different sites on your server. You can give them `SSH` and `SFTP` access to a specific site without allowing them access to other sites on the same server. It also can prevent malicious code in one site from affecting another site on the same server if these sites have different users.
See https://blog.laravel.com/forge-user-isolation